# npm update dependency issue

Tags: node.js, npm

I am trying to update dependencies for various projects I have on GitHub. I wanted to update them one at a time. I went through these steps:

1. npm update (from master)
2. npm update dependency-name (from folder containing the json files)
3. npm install dependency-name --save
4. npm fix --force (don't remember this command exactly. It was similar to that)

Then I got a message that said "--force. I hope you know what you're doing." I knew immediately that I'd made a mistake because I didn't know what I was doing. I found that command while Googling solutions, so I stopped there.

How can I update a specific dependency in a package-lock.json file?
Also, could I have done significant damage with the --force command?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

--force is a flag which forces a particular operation/process to run
So I think to fix the dependencies you would have used `npm audit fix --force`

You wouldn't have done any damage to your dependency tree.

The npm docs say:
`npm audit fix`
Scan your project for vulnerabilities and automatically install any compatible updates to vulnerable dependencies

Please refer https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/audit

Comment: That was definitely the command I used. Thank you for clearing that up for me.